# change image when hover

Tags: javascript, object, hover, mouseover

I want to change an SVG image when hover

these are my imports

```
import sebhag from "./assets/Menu/grey/sebha-g.svg"    
import sebhaw from "./assets/Menu/white/sebha-w.svg"

export const menu = {
    title_sebhag: 'tasbieh',
    image_sebhag: sebhag,
    image_sebhaw: sebhaw,
};
```

I want to change the `sebha-g.svg` to `sebha-w.svg` when hover

```
<button>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
       <img src={image_sebhag} alt=" " />
       <figcaption>{title_sebhag}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional context, the easiest way is probably through CSS:

```html
<button>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
       <img class="figure-img src={image_sebhag} alt=" " />
       <img class="figure-img--hover" src={image_sebhaw} alt=" " />
       <figcaption>{title_sebhag}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</button>
```

```css
figure .figure-img--hover {
  display:none
}

figure:hover .figure-img {
  display: none;
}
figure:hover .figure-img--hover {
  display: unset;
}
```

Here we simply hide the original image while hovering and instead display the desired image. Though there are many ways to skin this cat...